# Pass url property through a proxy

Tags: php, ajax, proxy

I am running a proxy so I can perform an ajax request on data through the url parameters.  The proxy php looks like :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml');
$daurl = 'http://thesite.com/form.asp';
$handle = fopen($daurl, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

I am hitting the proxy with ajax that ends up appending a parameter like :

```
$j.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'sandbox/proxy.php',
            data: 'order=' + ordervalue,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
            $j("#result").html(response);
            }
        });
```

So the request is like sandbox/proxy.php?order=123

How can I grab that data (order=123) and append it to the $daurl variable (http://thesite.com/form.asp?order=123) so that I can have the proxy actually return something?

This is virgin territory for me so you can not over-explain =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

```
$daurl = 'http://thesite.com/form.asp';

//if you only want 'order':
if(isset($_GET['order'])) 
   $daurl .= '?order=' . $_GET['order'];

//if you want the entire query string:

if(strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
   $daurl .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` should contain order=123, so you could change $daurl as follows:

```
$daurl = 'http://thesite.com/form.asp';
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != ""){
    $daurl.='?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
```

Doing it this way will transfer everything passed on the query string.  If however, you want just the order part you can use $_GET['order'], you may want to do something like:

```
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : -1;
```

`$order` will be -1 if order was not passed in the query string, otherwise it will have the value.